# Node-redis client hang and never return so my express app also

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have an express app where I use Redis for cashing with Redis v4.1.0, at first it works fine and after some time, it doesn't give a response, and my whole app endpoint.

After debugging, I found that it hangs (like infinite) at redis.get(key) and everything below that never gets executed.
And also I tried adding legacyMode:true according to this: [redis freezes node server when connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178133/redis-freezes-node-server-when-connected) ,here it doesn't crush, but it never caches my content or executes any command.

Here is my configuration

```
import { createClient } from "redis";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const redisClient = createClient({
  url: `redis://:${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}@${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`,
  // legacyMode: true, // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178133/redis-freezes-node-server-when-connected
});

redisClient
  .connect()
  .catch((err) => console.log("Connection to failed: ", err))
  .then(() => {});

redisClient.on("connect", () => console.log("Redis Server Connected"));
redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Redis Server Connection Error ", err.message);
});
redisClient.on("SIGINT", () => {
  redisClient.quit();
});

export { redisClient };
```

And this is my redis use

```
 static async getCacheData(key) {
    try {
      console.log("Get redis key: ", key);
      const redisData = await redisClient.get(key);
      console.log("Redis key found: ", typeof redisData);
      if (redisData != null) return JSON.parse(redisData);
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error getting redis cache key: ", key, "  ", error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors before it hangs? Have you tried changing `disableOfflineQueue` to `true`(https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md)?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have exactly same issue making my production go down from time to time…

Comment: Same here. For reference, it works fine if you dont use "await" but use callback on `client.on('ready', () => {`